# Azure Function + Cosmos DB and Static clients

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

May be this is very obvious question for many. but it is not to me.

I am currently, working on Performance of cosmos DB with azure function. and one of the obvious solution is to create static client. which is working fine.

in current architecture I have Cosmos DB setup for each customer in the same instance. So, I guess I can use same cosmos client for different database Id and their respective containers. what if I have multiple end points and their databases with their own containers. How do i ensure I have static client set up for this scenario.

Please note that we are planning to have 2 types of subscriptions, one is with shared resources and other one is dedicated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Functions DI instead of a static client: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions

Have a service injected that maintains internally a `ConcurrentDictionary` or some structure with a list of clients per account.

The Azure Function uses this service and requests a client for an account, the service will get or add the client to the internal list.

The service is maintained as a Singleton, so the internal list of clients is also a singleton, and you only have 1 client per account that you use.

Example (please do not take this code literally):

```
public class CosmosService
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CosmosClient> clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CosmosClient>();

    public CosmosClient GetClientForEndpoint(string connectionString (or whatever account identifier you want) ) 
    {
        if (clients.TryGetValue(connectionString, out CosmosClient client)) 
        {
            return client;
        }
    
        CosmosClient newClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString, (add whatever CosmosClientOptions you want here));
        
        if (!clients.TryAdd(connectionString, newClient))
        {
            // Another concurrent thread added a client for the same key
            newClient.Dispose(); // Avoid leaks
            if (clients.TryGetValue(connectionString, out CosmosClient client)) 
            {
                return client;
            }
            
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Reaching here means something removed the client instance");
        }
        
        return newClient;
    }
}
```

You can then store that as a Singleton during Function initialization (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions/Startup.cs)

And on your Functions, you can obtain the CosmosService, call the GetClientForEndpoint for the account/connection that that Tenant uses (in the case of managing multiple accounts), and you obtain the instance for that account.

That way you are sharing client instances in the case where you need to maintain multiple clients for different Accounts, and this is done following the Singleton pattern (one client per account for the lifetime of the application).

Comment: See example in edited answer.